# iptables-restore failed at COMMIT line, no detailed description

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm trying to setup iptables (using iptables-restore) for a new server and was looking at the security docs from [Linode](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/securing-your-server#basic-iptables-rulesets-for-ipv4-and-ipv6), so basically used their templates for IPv4 and IPv6. These are both failing at the COMMIT message, but I guess the error is somewhere else.

```
alessio@scw-272444:~$ sudo iptables-restore < /tmp/v4
iptables-restore: line 37 failed
```

IPv4:

```
*filter

# Allow all loopback (lo0) traffic and reject traffic
# to localhost that does not originate from lo0.
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

# Allow ping and traceroute.
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT

# Allow SSH connections.
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere
# (the normal ports for web servers).
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Accept inbound traffic from established connections.
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Log what was incoming but denied (optional but useful).
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_INPUT_denied: " --log-level 7

# Reject all other inbound.
-A INPUT -j REJECT

# Log any traffic which was sent to you
# for forwarding (optional but useful).
-A FORWARD -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_FORWARD_denied: " --log-level 7

# Reject all traffic forwarding.
-A FORWARD -j REJECT

COMMIT
```

IPv6:

```
*filter

# Allow all loopback (lo0) traffic and reject traffic
# to localhost that does not originate from lo0.
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -s ::1/128 -j REJECT

# Allow ICMP
-A INPUT  -p icmpv6 -j ACCEPT

# Allow HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere
# (the normal ports for web servers).
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Accept inbound traffic from established connections.
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Log what was incoming but denied (optional but useful).
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "ip6tables_INPUT_denied: " --log-level 7

# Reject all other inbound.
-A INPUT -j REJECT

# Log any traffic which was sent to you
# for forwarding (optional but useful).
-A FORWARD -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "ip6tables_FORWARD_denied: " --log-level 7

# Reject all traffic forwarding.
-A FORWARD -j REJECT

COMMIT
```

Comment: You should first post the eror message you get, then search your /var/log directory for iptables-related error messages. In doubt, sift thru `cd /var/log; grep -nrI iptables`.  Then post here what you find.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae unfortunately `iptables-restore: line 37 failed` is all I get. I've searched the logs and there's nothing related to an error unfortunately.

Comment: Right at the end of the file makes me think it's expecting a trailing newline character or something like that.  If that's not it, and if that's all it's giving you, the only other option would be to run each of the rules individually and see which one fails.

Answer (score 1):

Please add a new line after `COMMIT` or at the end of file. It will resolve your issue.  New line must be the last character.

Comment: In this case @Community is incorrect, this simple answer was my problem as well. When editing with nano I had to make sure I explicitly added a newline after the final `COMMIT`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The line COMMIT failed because maybe there are some mistakes before this line. Please check each single line in your configuration (paste it as arguments for iptables).

Or you can convert your iptables configuration as a bash script and run bash -x to view the misconfiguration:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# this file is: iptables_v4.sh

# Allow all loopback (lo0) traffic and reject traffic
# to localhost that does not originate from lo0.
iptables -A  INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A  INPUT ! -i lo -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

# Allow ping and traceroute.
iptables -A  INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A  INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A  INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT

# Allow SSH connections.
iptables -A  INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere
# (the normal ports for web servers).
iptables -A  INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A  INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Accept inbound traffic from established connections.
iptables -A  INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Log what was incoming but denied (optional but useful).
iptables -A  INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_INPUT_denied: " --log-level 7

# Reject all other inbound.
iptables -A  INPUT -j REJECT

# Log any traffic which was sent to you
# for forwarding (optional but useful).
iptables -A  FORWARD -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_FORWARD_denied: " --log-level 7

# Reject all traffic forwarding.
iptables -A  FORWARD -j REJECT
```

**To Debug:**:

```
root$bash -x iptables_v4.sh
```